# Travis Issues with Numpy Dependencies

Tags: python, numpy, travis-ci

I'm having some trouble using Travis for one of my projects, specifically issues dealing with Numpy dependencies.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/EthanWelsh/Yulp/builds/119268316) is the log of the failed build. I'm especially perplexed by this issue, because the log seems to show that pip installed all the required dependencies perfectly. However, later on in the log, Travis fails to load several of the classes.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Ethan

Comment: Link-only questions aren't very helpful to people searching for similar errors. It'd be good if you included a more thorough description of the error in the question. Copying the relevant portion of the build log would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to install all of those packages from source, and it's complaining that it can't find any BLAS or LAPACK to use. Adding apt packages for BLAS and LAPACK so that the build works will help, but installing that much from source is likely to take most (if not all) of your build time. I'd recommend using conda/miniconda to install binary builds of the dependencies you need instead.
Something like this should work.

```
before_install:
  - wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
  - bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
  - export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

After that you can add additional conda install commands as needed.